# Fix overlapping categories in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a dataset which contains a categorical feature depicting ranges.
The categories of this feature are the ordered value ranges.

In this particular dataset however, there is one category which spans multiple other categories. The code snippet below shows an example of such an occurrence.

Notice the category `11-30` spans `11-20` and `21-30`.

```py
data = ['1-10', '11-20','1-10','11-30','11-20','1-10','21-30','30+']

cat = pd.Categorical(data, categories=['1-10', '11-20','21-30','11-30', '30+'], ordered=True)
```

My approach to handle this is to keep the larger category and group the two smaller categories into that one. One way of doing is by simply replacing all occurrences of those entries with the value of the wider category, as shown here:

```py
s = pd.Series(cat)
s.replace(
    {'11-20': '11-30', 
     '21-30':'11-30'
})
print(s)
```

Which outputs:

```
0     1-10
1    11-30
2     1-10
3    11-30
4    11-30
5     1-10
6    11-30
7      30+
dtype: object
```

However, this seems like a very crude solution to a problem which must have popped up multiple times in history.

My question is thus: **what is the best way of fixing overlapping categories using pandas?**

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended way that you can select unique/distinct values from `pandas.Series` object.

`.unique()` method on `pandas.Series` allows you to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['1-10', '11-20','1-10','11-30','11-20','1-10','21-30','30+']
cat = pd.Categorical(data, categories=['1-10', '11-20','21-30','11-30', '30+'], ordered=True)

s = pd.Series(cat)
s.replace(
    {'11-20': '11-30', 
     '21-30':'11-30'
})

# Now .unique() method removes duplicated categories from series
unique_cats = s.unique() # unique categories
unique_series = pd.Series(unique_cats)  # This converts to pandas series
```

Comment: Although this might be useful if I wanted a way of reducing categorical data to their unique categories, that was not the original question.